# If $b\ne 0$, orthogonally diagonalize \begin{bmatrix}a&0&b\\0&a&0\\b&0&a\end{bmatrix}

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues as the first step of this problem, but it's leading me down this rabbit hole of countless computations to find all the eigenvalues. I'm confident I'm supposed to solve this a different way that is less tedious. Anyone able to give me a hand?

Comment: If you know one eigenvalue of a 3x3 then you can reduce the characteristic polynomial to a quadratic to be able to find the other two.

Comment: Orthogonally diagonalize the matrix ... Is this an equivalent problem: take the three columns of the matrix (in some order) and apply the Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: Why is it tedious? "Countless computations"?! Have you actually tried to find the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3):

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}a&0&b\\0&a&0\\b&0&a\end{bmatrix}\implies |A-xI_3|= \begin{vmatrix}a-x&0&b\\0&a-x&0\\b&0&a-x\end{vmatrix}=(a-x)^3-b^2(a-x).$

Solving $(a-x)^3-b^2(a-x)=0,$ we have, $x=a$ or $(a-x)^2-b^2=0\implies x\in\{a-b,a+b\}$.

Hence, the eigenvalues are $a,a-b$ and $a+b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be your matrix. Then $M-aI$ has a row of zeroes so one eigenvalues is $a$. The other eigenvalues must then add up to $2a$ (since the trace of the $3×3$ matrix is $3a$) and have determinant $a^2-b^2$ (taking minors of the second row shows the $3×3$ determinant is $a(a^2-b^2)$). Thus the eigenvalues end up $\{a,a\pm b\}$.

Answer (score 0):

the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1 \\
1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

are $1,-1$  with eigenvectors as the columns of (orthogonal)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1 \\
0&0&0 \\
1&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

are $1,0,-1$  with eigenvectors as the columns of (orthogonal)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\\
0&1&0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&b \\
0&0&0 \\
b&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

are $b,0,-b$  with eigenvectors as the columns of (orthogonal)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\\
0&1&0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

the eigenvalues of
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&0&b \\
0&a&0 \\
b&0&a \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

are $a+b,a,a-b$  with eigenvectors as the columns of (orthogonal)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}\\
0&1&0 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}&0& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: The trick is that adding a multiple of the identity, specifically, just shifts all the eigenvalues. Generally adding two matrices doesn't result in the eigenvalues being added.